# Select background Color Based On Condition In WPF without loosing hover effect

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this Style:

```
<Style x:Key="MenuBtn" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PN_ColorFondoAcentoClaro}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="240"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="55"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{DynamicResource PN_FontFamily}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource PN_FontSizeMediana}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource PN_ColorFuenteOscuro}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border 
                        BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PN_ColorFondoAcentoClaro}"
                        BorderThickness="0.5"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="5">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource PN_ColorAlerta}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="10"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation To="220" Duration="0:0:0.7" 
                                        AccelerationRatio="0.10" DecelerationRatio="0.10" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Width)" />
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.7" 
                                        AccelerationRatio="0.10" DecelerationRatio="0.15" 
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Width)" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SetHoverBackgroundStoryboard}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource RestoreBackgroundStoryboard}"/>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFavorite}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PN_ColorFondoAcentoClaro}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFavorite}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I need to show some options, some ones are marked as  favorites with **IsFavorite** property. I want to show a diferente color when IsFavorite is active. I used two datatriggers for it

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFavorite}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource PN_ColorFondoAcentoClaro}"/>
</DataTrigger>
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsFavorite}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

They works pretty well, but my mouse hover now shows nothing. Thats why I tryed

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SetHoverBackgroundStoryboard">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
            KeyTime="0:0:0"
            Value="{StaticResource PN_ColorAlerta}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>

<Storyboard x:Key="RestoreBackgroundStoryboard">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame 
            KeyTime="0:0:0"
            Value="{StaticResource PN_ColorFondoAcentoClaro}" />
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

**SetHoverBackgroundStoryboard** sets my background like hover, but when I use **RestoreBackgroundStoryboard** don't know how to use **IsFavorite** to show my original color again.

There is a way to combine DataTrigger and EventTrigger to solve it?
How to avoid loose hover background effect when DataTrigger change my control background?

or

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Using DataTriggers gets really complicated really fast.  These days controls tend to use Visual States to achieve complicated effects like this.    Have you looked into that?  You can define arbitrary groups of states that show/hide/animate properties at will

Comment: @Joe I'm not familiarized with it. but I'm going to take a look.

Comment: It's a bit verbose but the nice thing about it is that it is *declarative* rather than procedural.   If you want to see examples, try making copies of the existing templates of existing controls while using the Xaml Designer.  You'll have a wealth of examples to copy from.  .   And read up on the `VisualStateManager` in the MS documentation.  Long term I think that's the better approach.  You just have to deal with the learning curve

Comment: @Joe Time is a little shrot right now. But Hands on it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DataTrigger`  to combine several conditions, for example that `IsFavorite` is `true` *and* `IsMouseOver` is also `true`:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsFavorite}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
</MultiDataTrigger>
```